# Mostrar/esconder div ao selecionar opção de um select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Preciso fazer com que ao selecionar a opção de um select apareça uma `div`.

Estou utilizando angular, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Sem código fica difícil, mas pode usar javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só usar a diretiva [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainController', function($scope){
  $scope.mostrarDiv = false;
  $scope.opcoes = [
    { descr: "Mostrar", valor: true },
    { descr: "Não mostrar", valor: false }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
  <select ng-options="opcao.valor as opcao.descr for opcao in opcoes" ng-model="mostrarDiv"></select>
  
  <div ng-show="mostrarDiv">
    Alguma coisa
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Brother ajudou, desculpe pois não sei nada de Angular estou começando e precisava com urgência, Agradeço!